# Payment method in Checkout page issue in Magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, onepage-checkout

I am facing the serious issue which road block for the order placement in my Magento instance. I have made some customization in Checkout side. And it was working properly. Suddenly, I am facing this issue like, **getting Payment method instead of Shipping address template**.[image]

I don't know what wrong with that, because no error is showing in console.

Comment: can you post your checkout_index_index

Comment: i have disabled all custom modules related to Checkout .Now it is using default checkout_index_index. after that also the same issue existing

Answer (score 0):

That is not a issue. Customer may be selected downloadable or virtual product. Thus checkout section being like this